# QML, Qt 5.11: SwipeView acting instead of SwipeDelegate

Tags: qt, qml, swipe

I have a SwipeView and inside I have a Repeater with a SwipeDelegate. The problem is that sometimes when I swipe the repeater item it registers as a swipe on the SwipeDelegate, which I want, but sometimes it registers as a swipe on the SwipeView and changes the page, which I don't want. Code below for clarity.

Is there anyway to give priority to the SwipeDelegate so it always takes priority over the SwipeView? Or is it just bad practice to implement this type of nested swipe areas?

I tried using z-order as seen in the code but that doesn't help.

```
TabBar {
    id: appTabBar
    contentContainer: swipeView

    TabButton {
        text: "Add History"
    }

    TabButton {
        text: "View History"
    }
}

QC2.SwipeView {
    id: swipeView
    anchors.top: appTabBar.bottom
    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    width: parent.width
    clip: true
    z: 1

    Item {}

    Item {

        Column {
            id: table
            width: parent.width
            spacing: 3

            Repeater {
                id: foodTableRepeater
                height: dp(20)
                model: []
                delegate: QC2.SwipeDelegate {
                    id: swipeDelegate
                    width: parent.width

                    Rectangle {
                        height: parent.height
                        width: parent.width
                        color: (index % 2 === 0) ? "#D3F2FF" : "#FFFFFF"
                        border.color: "blue"
                        border.width: dp(1)
                        z: 2

                        Row {
                            height: parent.height
                            width: parent.width
                            AppText {
                                id: date
                                leftPadding: dp(10)
                                width: parent.width
                                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                                text: JSFuns.getLocaleDateTime(app.locale, modelData[2], app.use_24)
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    swipe.right: QC2.Label {
                        id: deleteLabel
                        verticalAlignment: QC2.Label.AlignVCenter
                        padding: 5
                        width: parent.width * 0.4 / 3
                        height: parent.height
                        anchors.right: parent.right
                        z: 3
                        Icon {
                            width: parent.width
                            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                            icon: IconType.close
                            size: parent.height
                            color: "red"
                        }

                        QC2.SwipeDelegate.onClicked: console.debug(index)

                        background: Rectangle {
                            color: deleteLabel.QC2.SwipeDelegate.pressed ?
                                       Qt.darker(app.color_secondary_light, 1.1) :
                                       app.color_secondary_light
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide an example that runs.

Comment: @Mitch I'm not sure I can fully. This is the most basic implementation of what I'm doing I can think of but my app wrapper elements come from V-Play, an external source. The only code outside my code above is Page{} then elements derived from StackView then App{}. In addition, to make self-sufficient code, I would need to add in database creation code so there is something that the Repeater can pull from as possibly the fact that I'm using Javascript to dynamically create the Repeater elements may be part of my problem. I hope that helps explain.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got a fix that seems to work well. I modified the SwipeDelegate as follows:

```
delegate: QC2.SwipeDelegate {
    id: swipeDelegate
    width: parent.width
    onPressed: swipeView.interactive = false // New line
    onCanceled: swipeView.interactive = true // New line
```

These two added lines simply turn on and off the SwipeView, turning it off while the SwipeDelegate is being interacted with and back on when the user finishes.

The only drawback so far is I can't use the SwipeView by swiping the SwipeDelegate to the right. However, this is very minor.